# How to store different variables in session array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm making a basic Chat Box with PHP. Basically I don't want to use database connection for sending message to a user. Instead of that, I like storing different values that a user send in a session array.

For example take a a look at this:

```
<?php 
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['messages'] = array();  
}
if (isset($_POST['send'])){
    $pm = $_POST['message'];
    array_push($_SESSION['messages'], $pm); 
    $request_params = [
        'chat_id' => $id,
        'text' => implode(" ", $_SESSION['messages'])
    ];
    print_r($request_params);
}
?>
<div class="box-footer">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Write your direct message" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <input name="send" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat"/>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

As you can see it basically store the `message` that user typed in a variable called `$pm` and by this sentence: `'text' => implode(" ", $_SESSION['messages'])` it will simple push **string** value of `$pm` into `$_SESSION['messages']`.

Then I try to save the `$id` value (no need to include the code of id here, it is just an id of user) as  `chat_id` and `$_SESSION['messages']` as `text`.

Now in order to test this out I tried `print_r($request_params);` but it just shows only this:

```
Array ( [chat_id] => 108132368 [text] => )
```

As you can see it does not return the session variable which is `$_SESSION['messages'])`.

So why it does not work ? How can I store different variables in a session array ?

**UPDATE 1:**

```
    <?php 
session_start();
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    $_SESSION['messages'] = array();  
}
if (isset($_POST['send'])){
    $pm = $_POST['message'];
    array_push($_SESSION['messages'], $pm); 
    $request_params = [
        'chat_id' => $id,
        'text' => implode(" ", $_SESSION['messages'])
    ];
    echo $_SESSION['messages'];
    print_r($request_params);}
?>
<div class="box-footer">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Write your direct message" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <input name="send" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat"/>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Its work fine and give output `Array ( [chat_id] => 1 [text] => ss )`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may lie here

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['messages'] = array();  
}
```

The variable `$_SESSION['messages']` is being overwritten on each page load so perhaps change to

```
session_start();
if( empty( $_SESSION['messages'] ) ) $_SESSION['messages'] = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code as below:

```
<?php

//check if a session has been defined earlier somewhere.
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
    session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['messages']))
    $_SESSION['messages'] = array();

if (isset($_POST['send'])){
   // your code...
}
```

Initially your problem was that you created a fresh array every time the form was submitted (sorry, I misunderstood your purpose earlier).

However, you should not be declaring the `$_SESSION['messages']` inside the `session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE` condition. You need to see if `$_SESSION['messages']` array is already defined, and if not, define that. Use an `isset()` to do that.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: can you please add the updated code so we can see what's wrong?

Comment: Sure, checkout **UPDATE 1**.

Comment: Hi, you can remove the updated code, it's not necessary.

Comment: If you still have the issue after adding this code, close the browser and open it again. (or else call to session_destroy(); towards the end of your script, load the page, then remove the line, and load the page again.)

Comment: I Posted a new question about this, please view it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954198/array-push-expects-parameter-1-to-be-array-null-given-php-error-message?noredirect=1#comment82877636_47954198)

Comment: Check the code in my updated answer. the code snippet you have posted in your new question is buggy. :)