# array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given php error message

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm trying to save some values from a variable into my session array with php.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php 
session_start();
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    $_SESSION['messages'] = array();  
}
$request_params = array();
if (isset($_POST['send'])){
    $pm = $_POST['message'];
    array_push($_SESSION['messages'], $pm); 
    $request_params = [
        'chat_id' => $id,
        'text' => implode(" ", $_SESSION['messages'])
    ];
    echo $_SESSION['messages'];
    print_r($request_params);
}
?>
<div class="box-footer">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Write your direct message" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <input name="send" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat"/>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And these are the errors that appear when I try to submit the form:

**Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in new.php on line 9**

**Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in new.php on line 12**

Line 9:

> array_push($_SESSION['messages'], $pm);

And line 12:

> 'text' => implode(" ", $_SESSION['messages'])

So how to solve these issues ?

Comment: This means that `$_SESSION['messages']` is not __defined__

Comment: But I have defined as you can see at the top of my code.

Comment: I suppose that you don't.

Comment: @u_mulder What do u mean by I suppose that you don't ?! I have pasted my code here and it is the way it is. Explain me what is your talking about man

Comment: If you think about your code you can understand that __maybe__ `session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE` is __false__ and your code inside `if` is not executed. Isn't it?

Comment: `$_SESSION['messages']` could be string if `session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE` condition doesn't math

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error : **Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given**

because your `$_SESSION['messages']` variable is never set.

When this part of your code gets executed,

```
session_start();
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    $_SESSION['messages'] = array();  
}
```

The first line starts a new session. So `session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE` will never be `true` since `session_status()` returns 2 and `PHP_SESSION_NONE` equals to 1. As a result, $_SESSION['messages'] = array(); will not get executed.

What you need to be doing is, check if a session has been started, and start one if not.

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

This will check if you have a session_start() called somewhere earlier in your script.

Then after that, add this line:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['messages']))
    $_SESSION['messages'] = array();
```

Hope it helps.